# PrimeNG Dynamic Dialog instance/ content of component

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, primeng

I have problem with dynamic dialog in PrimeNg.

Is there any option to handle other actions on a dialog besides `close`?

For example, in `Kendo-UI` dialog example I can define content.instance of the component and I can access the fields of the component instance opened as dialog.

```
  const ref = this.dialogService.open(ResourceComponent, {
        data: {
            logicFormGroup: this.formGroup,
            resources: this.resources$
        }, width: '700px'
    });

    ref.onClose.subscribe((back: ResourceModel) => {
        console.log(back);
    });

   ref.addPersonEmitter.sub(....)

   in component ResourceComponent
   @Output() addPersonEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible with PrimeNG DynamicDialog. Other libraries (NG-Zorro's Antd for example) let you directly pass in values to a component's @Input and then explicitly subscribe to your component outputs after creating the dialog. For some reason, PrimeNG doesn't let you do this. You can kinda work around this by modifying the component in your dialog to close the dialog with an action tag, and then subscribing to ref.onClose and handling your actions. This means you can't easily do any actions though. The other option is to pass in a callback function through the data object. It's messy..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i solve it by passing eventemitter to dialog data and subscribed to that refernce

in parent

```
    oneventFire : EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
this.dialogService.open(MyPopupComponent,
      {data: {  oneventFire : this.oneventFire },
```

in child

```
 if (this.config && this.config.data) { 
      this.oneventFire = this.config.data.oneventFire ;
    }
```

so then you can subscribe in parent and emit in children

Answer (score 7):

I had the same Issue and solved it like this:

```
const ref = this.dialogService.open(ComponentType, {});
let dialogRef = this.dialogService.dialogComponentRefMap.get(ref);
dialogRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
const instance = dialogRef.instance.componentRef.instance as ComponentType;
instance.someOutput.subscribe(() =>{ doSomething(); });
```

The call to detectChanges is necessary to trigger the dynamic dialog to load the component, otherwise the componentRef on the instance would be undefined. This is because the component just gets loaded in the ngAfterViewInit of the dialog.

Don't forget to unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy...

Comment: when trying to call detectChanges it throw exception

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 11 with  "primeng": "11.2.0"